# Regex for repeating text matching same pattern

Tags: regex

Trying to extract groups of repeating IP data from a specific start point, but where number of repeating items is unknown. In the below example I want any and all IP addresses for the entry 'Host (Origin)'. This is as far as I've got, which isn't that far, and doesn't work.

```
Host \(Origin\):\s+((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*\n)+
```

Note the IPs can have data after it but not required, i.e. each ip is on a new line other than the first...

https://regex101.com/r/3qtn6G/2

In the example below it should return 169.254.11.2, 10.14.75.67, 172.165.123.36, 172.165.123.37 as four groups.

```
Rule Block 1:                 Log Observed
Host (Origin):                169.254.11.2 (2)
10.14.75.67 (2)
172.165.123.36 (4)
172.165.123.37
HostName (Origin):
IP Address (Impacted):        169.165.123.36 (4)
User (Origin):
Domain (Impacted):
Domain (Origin):
Network (Origin):
```

Comment: What tool/language/app/framework are you using, and why would you insist on using regex to do the grouping?

Comment: You can get them more or less easily as separate matches depending on the regex flavor. PCRE example: `(?:\G(?!\A)(?:\s*\(\d+\)\s*)?|Host\s*\(Origin\):)\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNv4Aj/1))

Comment: @wiktor thanks, this is perfect and works. Add as answer if you wish.

Comment: @mathias because regex is the best tool for this requirement of extracting IP. But to answer, it is also the only tool I have with the framework I am using as it's not code based :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get these strings as separate matches using the PCRE-compliant pattern like

```
(?:\G(?!\A)(?:\s*\(\d+\)\s*)?|Host\s*\(Origin\):)\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+){3}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNv4Aj/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)(?:\s*\(\d+\)\s*)?|Host\s*\(Origin\):)` - either `Host` + zero or more whitespaces + `(Origin):` or the end of the previous match and then an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces + `(` + one or more digits + `)` + zero or more whitespaces
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` - a substring of four dot-separated one or more digit chunks

Comment: Thanks for the help, lookahead/back always confuses me as does changing state like with \K :)